# vba IE automation Show drop down list options in web page

Tags: vba

i want to click on the object dropdownlist (select tag) in webpage and wants to show the options available to the user. But when i perform click / fireevent("onlick"), the object is getting clicked but the dorp down is not expanding with the available options. (I dont want to select the value, but i want to show the avilable options in dropdown to user). I have already tried the follwing options

```
object.click
object.fireevent("onclick")
object.fireevent("onmousedown")
object.fireevent("onmouseup")
object.fireevent("ondblclick").
```

But nothing is worked. please advise on how can i achieve this action

Comment: Can you share an URL? Can you share the page code? What actions on the page make this drop down appear? The user will be interacting with the drop down anyway so why the need to have the drop down expanded? If your site, change to radio buttons/check boxes.

Comment: Thanks for response QHarr. the url is not available out side of organization.any general/public website solution also is fine for me if we can achieve this action. please advise

Comment: Without seeing the page I don't know what to advise. Normally .Click on the Select tag element suffices. Sometimes you need a FireEvent or combination of FireEvents.

Comment: Thanks QHarr. i tried even with fire event options. still i am unable to do this action. I tried even with gmail application. still i had the same trouble in showing up the drop down options on page. so you can try with any public website to see the trouble in acheiving this.